# The dual space of a product space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $\prod^n L^1(I) $ is the product space of n $L^1$ integrable functions. What would be its dual space of continous linear functionals? would it be $\prod^n L^{\infty}(I)$? Do I need the norm for the product space to define the dual?

Comment: Yes, the dual is (for reasonable norms) always $\prod^n L^{\infty}(I)$, but the norm depends on the norm you choose in $\prod^n L^1(I)$.

Comment: Thanks. So is it to possible to choose some norm for  $ \prod^n L^1(I)$ such that for $(x,y)$ in the dual,$ || (x,y)||=\max\{ || x||_{\infty}, || y||_{\infty}\}$, where $||.||_{\infty} $is the usual $L^{\infty}$ norm?

Comment: Yes, just take $\| (x,y)\| = \|x\|_{L^1} + \|y\|_{L^1}$ as norm in $\prod L^1$.

Comment: To make sure I understand, we may replace $L^1, L^{\infty}$ by $L^2 $ and keep define the same max norm and sum norm for primal and dual as above?

Comment: Yes, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X$ be any Banach space, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \le p \le \infty$.

On the space $\prod_{i=1}^n X$ we define the norm
\begin{equation*}
 \lVert (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \rVert
 :=
 \Big(
  \sum_{i = 1}^n \lVert x_i \rVert_X^p
 \Big)^{1/p}.
\end{equation*}
In case $p = \infty$
this is to be understood as
\begin{equation*}
 \lVert (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \rVert
 :=
 \max_{i = 1,\ldots,n} \lVert x_i \rVert_{X}.
\end{equation*}
Then, the dual of $\prod_{i=1}^n X$
is
$\prod_{i=1}^n X^*$
with the norm
\begin{equation*}
 \lVert (x_1^*, \ldots, x_n^*) \rVert
 :=
 \Big(
  \sum_{i = 1}^n \lVert x_i^* \rVert_{X^*}^q
 \Big)^{1/q},
\end{equation*}
where $q$ is the conjugate exponent to $p$, i.e., $1/p + 1/q = 1$.
In case $q = \infty$, i.e., $p = 1$,
this is to be understood as
\begin{equation*}
 \lVert (x_1^*, \ldots, x_n^*) \rVert
 :=
 \max_{i = 1,\ldots,n} \lVert x_i^* \rVert_{X^*}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Here all the conclusions on the dual and product norm on the dual could be extended to $\prod^n_i X$ can be replaced by $\prod^n_i X_i$ with each $X_i$ different? i.e. the dual of $\prod^n_i X_i$ will be $\prod^n_i X_i^*$ and its norm is given similarly as above?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It is also not hard to prove.